# Displaying results from different tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to work this out for the last hour.  my college tutor give me this question and I cant figure out what to do.

The question is:

**Show all Counties in the UK where one direction has performed**

this is the db and tables:

```
CITY (Name, County, Country)
THEATRE (Name, City, County, Capacity)
SHOW (Title, Artist, Venue, Attendance)
```

This is my answer:

```
SELECT country from theatre
INNER JOIN show
ON theatre.name = show.venue
WHERE artist = 'one direction'
AND county=(

     SELECT country FROM theatre 
     INNER JOIN city
     ON theatre.city = city.name
     WHERE city.country = 'UK'
)
```

Am I close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  THEATRE.County AS CountyFromTheatre,
  CITY.County AS CountyFromCity,
FROM SHOW
INNER JOIN THEATRE ON THEATRE.NAME=`SHOW`.Venue
INNER JOIN CITY ON CITY.NAME=THETARE.City
WHERE `SHOW`.Artist='one direction'
AND CITY.Country='UK'
```

Observation #1: Mind the backticks on SHOW - it generally is bad style to use a reserved word as a table name.

Observation #2: The CITY table and the THEATRE both have the County. This is bad design - imagine a venue having county "A" while the city has county "B"